# C++ Probllem with output

Tags: c++, string, random, output

I need the user to type what file he want to write the data too.
Example: What text file do you want to write "Hello Too"?
He types to: example, and the data will come to the example.txt file and it will contain Hello Too. The problem is that it cant take a string (accname) and and combine .txt to make it send the data too that text file. Its hard to explain, hope you understand :D

```
int Transfersum;
string accname;
cout << "Type the account name you want to send too" << endl;
cin >> accname;

ofstream mfile;
mfile.open ( accname ".txt");
mfile << Transfersum;
mfile.close();
```

Comment: String concatenation is in the first couple chapters of any good book.

Comment: mfile.open ( accname + ".txt"); to concatenate strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use string concatenation with `+`.

```
mfile.open ( accname + ".txt");
```

If you are not on `c++ 11`, then you probably need a C-style string.

```
mfile.open ( (accname + ".txt").c_str());
```

Comment: get this error:   73 32 C:\Users\Winston\Desktop\C++\main.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::basic_string<char>)'

Comment: Worked thanks :D Anything i can do to reward u?

Comment: I cant need to wait 5 min, but i will do it then.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to concatenate the `accname + ".txt"` to use it as parameter expression for the `mfile.open ()` call.